# Find n term of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, pattern-recognition

A sequence is given:

$$1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,\dots,a_n,\dots$$

The question is: what is the value of $a_n$ for a given $n$?

I have tried a lot of patterns but was not able to meet the general term. Its clear that it follows decimal code pattern with base of 2.

Answer (score 12):

This is just the sequence of positive integers expressed in base two: $a_n$ is the base-two representation of the positive integer $n$. There's not really much more to be said.

Comment: But is their any way to figure out general term other than this

Comment: @Bharat: Just convert $n$ to base two. There are standard algorithms for that.

Comment: Can you give me details regarding that algor--

Comment: @Bharat: You can find descriptions of the two most common pencil-and-paper algorithms [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).

Comment: here's a page for all types of conversion problems and the algorithms; decimal, octal, binary, hex, etc. http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/inclass/conversions.html

Answer (score 1):

As Brian M. Scott already said, there isn't much more to say about your series. It's only about converting bases. But please note that, given only the first few elements of this series, there could be many series that make sense. I've described one way to find a series that makes sense [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/438001/6876).

## Converting a number from decimal to base two

I guess you can convert from base 10 to base 2 in many ways, but two standard ways are the Euclidean algorithm and the [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) (LaTeX-sources for the following images are [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/source-code))

### Euclidean algorithm

[image]

### Horner schema

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this series :
$$\underbrace{0_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}1_{⠀⠀9⠀⠀}10_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}11_{⠀⠀89⠀⠀}100_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}}\underbrace{101_{⠀⠀9⠀⠀}110_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}111_{⠀⠀890⠀⠀}1000_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}}1001_{⠀⠀9⠀⠀}1010_{⠀⠀1⠀⠀}1011_{⠀⠀8900⠀⠀}9911$$

I've marked the terms which are following a pattern in their differences . I've divided the terms in $4$ types :

$\underline{TYPE.1}$ If $n=4x+1$ where , $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,......\}$

> $$a_n=11x+\frac{89(10^{x}-1)}{9}$$

[ $Note:$ this is only applicable for $n\in\{5,9,13,17,.....\}$ ]

$$---------------------------------------$$

$\underline{TYPE.2}$ If $n=4x$ where , $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,......\}$

> $$a_n=11x+\frac{89(10^{x-1}-1)}{9}$$

[ $Note:$ this is only applicable for $n\in\{4,8,12,16,.....\}$ ]

$$---------------------------------------$$

$\underline{TYPE.3}$ If $n=2(2y+1)$ where , $y\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,......\}$ $$a_n=a_{4m+1}+1$$

> $$a_n=11y+\frac{89(10^{y}-1)}{9}+1$$

[ $Note:$ this is only applicable for $n\in\{2,6,10,14,.....\}$ ]

$$---------------------------------------$$

$\underline{TYPE.3}$ If $n=2(2y+1)+1$ where , $y\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,......\}$ $$a_n=a_{2(2y+1)}+9$$

> $$a_n=11y+\frac{89(10^{y}-1)}{9}+10$$

[ $Note:$ this is only applicable for $n\in\{3,7,11,15,.....\}$ ]

Comment: DownVoters please provide the mistakes too